# MongoDB weighting queries without reducing performance

Tags: mongodb

I have 2 query conditions that I want to match, but I’d like the documents that match the first condition to be ordered first in the results. I also don’t want to return any duplicate results.

This is how the basic query would look but wouldn’t order them as I would like:

```
Model.find({ $or: [
    { field1: query1 },
    { field2: query2 }
]})
```

I can get them in the desired order by doing the following:

```
Model.find({ field1: query1 })
Model.find({
    field2: query2,
    field1: { $ne: query1 }
})
```

Then returning the results and displaying them one after the after. This works reasonably well but the `$ne` to avoid duplicates just feels inefficient and requires me to add an extra field to my indexes.

I’m aware that I could use `$addFields` to add something such as `matches_first` and `matches_second` as a Boolean for each document and then `$sort: { matches_first: -1, matches_second: -1 }` but I feel that adds a lot of processing time, especially if you’re working with a large collection.

Is this `addFields` method reasonably efficient or not?

Is there a simpler way to run a query with multiple conditions that returns its results in the order of the conditions?

Comment: What do you mean by "it feels inefficient"? Did you test? Are you not happy with the performance?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit well it requires me to add an extra index field which increases storage. Performance isn't bad but I'm running 2 queries per request when I feel like there must be a way to do it in one. Just feels like bad code.

Comment: How many documents would typically match the (full) query?